# Mysqli login - Am i protected against Sql injection with this code?

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

I've been cruising on the forums for a while now and I was wondering if this is a secure decent way to create a login in mysqli.

It seems too easy and i'm not sure because the tutorial isn't using prepared statements...

[Mysqli - Login tutorial](http://www.onlinetuting.com/create-login-script-in-php/)

Is this a proper way of doing things?

I also found this and this seems "decent"

How does the daily programmer do this?

Is PDO so much more adviced even if your only using it for things such as databases for clubs, stores etc....rather than a big firm?

[Better way?](http://w3epic.com/php-mysql-login-system-a-super-simple-tutorial/)

Comment: unformatted code, tables being used for layout, no prepared statements, unhashed passwords! I'd stay away. http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: This is but one of probably thousands of tutorials out there. Keep searching, you'll find something. I sometimes spend up to 3 days on Google, *really*.

Comment: the tutorial appers to have a _very_ simple approach, it stores passwords in clear text. You should definitely not copy this approach verbatim.

Comment: Plus, the *important* thing about this tutorial that you *need to worry about*, is not the fact that it's not using prepared statements, it's the fact that it's using **plain text passwords** as a storage method. That's what you need to be mostly concerned about. It's using a data escaping function, so that's not too too bad. Here, this is much much better http://daveismyname.com/login-and-registration-system-with-php-bp - It uses PDO with prepared statements and `password_hash()`. THAT is what you should be using.

Comment: Why so many downvotes....i don't get it...

Comment: I only voted to close, I didn't downvote. One reason for the downvotes might be because your question is based on a tutorial, where they figure you could have done your research on the subject. I've given you a link above, which I hope you will be using instead of any of those two links. Questions like these are considered off-topic on Stack.

Comment: Thx for the information, i will be following that link! Could you tell me if its rly handy for me to switch to PDO if i'm only using databases for small companies, etc....

Comment: You're welcome Michael. You don't "need" to switch to PDO, you can get by in using `mysqli_` functions, but just as long as you use "prepared statements" [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and use PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). But big or small a company, data is data and if any gets hacked; you're done for.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I just feel more familiar with Mysqli as it makes more logic in style (for me that is). 

So to summarize: 

use prepared statements with Mysqli and use PHP password_hash(). 

Small extra question: How do I make certain pages only visible to logged in users? Do i put a script on those pages?

Comment: Also...you linked me a page where it shows a great example of a pdo connection/login. Could you point me in the right direction to a Mysqli example that is good? No logic in learning another bad method....

Comment: @Michael: see my profile for a tutorial that shows how to hash passwords correctly. It uses PDO but the principles apply also to MySQLi.

Comment: Could you link me the tutorial please?

Comment: You need to learn how to do this. Click on my name to view my profile, and then read my profile text on the right hand side. (To speak to individuals here, please use @halfer or whatever - people won't get a comment notification otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO might be a better way to go. It can provide for prepared statements which can remove instances of SQL injection attacks

Have a look at the manual for PHP's PDO [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. Take a look at these functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
You would hash the password using this function and store this in your database.

To verify a login you would fetch the hashed password and the salt and then use this function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Don't send the password to the server, rather query the hashed one and verify it. And take a look at PDO it's more advisable to use than MySQLi.

Comment: *"And take a look at pdo it's more advisable to use as MySQLi"* - `mysqli_` also has prepared statements http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php so it's just as good.

Comment: So many people advice me to use PDO but i'll be honest....i don't need it for supercomplicated stuff. I make websites and never work for big firms...more for small companies,stores....i'm allowed to handle the webdesign/developing etc... but i never did the databases etc...i had someone who did this for me professionally. But my interest kept growing and i'm looking to start learning more and more about this. So my question was....is it rly needed to go PDO if 'm not working for big firms, companies etc....

Comment: @Michael: PDO or MySQLi are both perfectly good. This answer indicates sometimes people prefer one over the other, just don't use the legacy library.